# Problem with tf tutorial

Tags: ros, tutorials, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rviz: Missing resource catkin
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/user/fuerte_workspace
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/lib
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
turtle_tf: Missing resource catkin
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/user/fuerte_workspace
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/lib
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
```

I get this error when I tried to do [tf/Tutorial/Introduction to tf].
Anyone else know how to solve this? Much appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83961/problem-with-tf-tutorial/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-09-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-09-26**:
I guess it is unable to locate package turtle_tf and rviz. Most probably the environment setup is not working properly. Check whether you are able to locate package rviz and turtle_tf using roscd command.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-09-28**:
What command is this the output from?

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-09-29**:
rosdep install turtle_tf rviz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you're missing this line in your rosdep sources (/etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list)

```
gbpdistro https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml fuerte
```

"gbpdistro https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml fuerte"

I believe it's required for fuerte but not newer.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0